# context.job_queue.run_once not working in Python Telegram BOT API

Tags: asynchronous, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to setup a bot which:

1. Receives the keywords in `/search_msgs userkey` command from a TG group
2. Search in DB for that `userkey` and send back appropriate text back

I'm getting two errors

1. None type object has no attribute args, in `callback_search_msgs(context)`, see code snippet
2. AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'job_queue', `in search_msgs(update, context)`, see code snippet.

Telegram's official documents is way too difficult for me to read and understand. Couldn't find even one place where Updater, update, Commandhandler, context are all explained together with examples.

How to fix this code?

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler, JobQueue

token = "Token"
bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)

# Search specific msgs on user request
def search_msgs(update, context):
    context.job_queue.run_once(callback_search_msgs, context=update.message.chat_id)


def callback_search_msgs(context):
    print('In TG, args', context.args)
    chat_id = context.job.context
    search_msgs(context, chat_id)



def main():
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("search_msgs",search_msgs, pass_job_queue=True,
                                  pass_user_data=True))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first try & clear something up:

> Telegram's official documents is way too difficult for me to read and understand. Couldn't find even one place where Updater, update, Commandhandler, context are all explained together with examples.

I'm guessing that by "Telegram's official documents" you mean the docs at https://core.telegram.org/bots/api. However, `Updater`, `CommandHandler` and `context` are concepts of `python-telegram-bot`, which is one (of many) python libraries that provides a wrapper for the bot api. `python-telegram-bot` provides a [tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot), [examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#examples), a [wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki) where a lots of the features are explained and [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

---

Now to your code:

1. In `context.job_queue.run_once(callback_search_msgs, context=update.message.chat_id)` you're not telling `job_queue` when to run the the job. You must pass an integer or a `datetime.(date)time` object as *second* argument.
2. in

   ```
   def callback_search_msgs(context):
       print('In TG, args', context.args)
       chat_id = context.job.context
       search_msgs(context, chat_id)
   ```

   you are passing `context` and `chat_id` to `search_msgs`. However, that function treats `context` as an instance of `telegram.ext.CallbackContext`, while you pass an integer instead. Also, even if that worked, this would just schedule another job in an infinite loop.

Finally, I don't understand what scheduling jobs has to do with looking up a key in a database. All you have to do for that is something like

```
def search_msgs(update, context):
    userkey = context.args[0]
    result = look_up_key_in_db(userkey)
    # this assumes that result is a string:
    update.effective_message.reply_text(result)
```

To understand `context.args` better, have a look at this [wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Types-Of-Handlers).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.